# Configuring "Do not forcefully unload the users registry at user logoff" in User Profiles of Group Policy editor

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-remoting, user-profile, group-policy

I need to write a PowerShell script that should configure the below settings of Group policy in all the machines.

*Gpedit.msc → Computer Configuration → Administrative Templates → System → User Profiles →  "Do not forcefully unload the users registry at user logoff"* to "Enabled".

As I am aware this can be done using the registry value also

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\System]
"DisableForceUnload"=dword:00000001
```

But through the script, when I add the required registry entry, the change is not reflected in the Group Policy console. Of course, I need to use the Group Policy cmdlets!
When I tried with `Set-GPRegistryValue` with below statement

```psh
Set-GPRegistryValue -Name "User Profiles" `
  -key "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\System\" `
  -ValueName DisableForceUnload -Type DWord -Value 1
```

It shows exception saying "A Referral was returned from the server."

```
Set-GPRegistryValue : A referral was returned from the server. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007202B)
At D:\Work\XYZ\Desktop\GPO1.ps1:6 char:1
+ Set-GPRegistryValue -Name "User Profiles" -key "HKLM\SOF ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Set-GPRegistryValue], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException,Microsoft.GroupPolicy.Commands.SetGPRegistryValue 
   Command
```

What exactly I missing out here?

Comment: Are you sure this is the right key `"HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\System\"`? Technet says group policies are stored here https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc939918.aspx, in particular, I would try `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System` instead

Comment: @VarvaraKalinina The "User Profiles" configuration settings will be stored  in the 
`HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\System\ ` I verified it.

Answer (score 0):

A domain controller returning a [referral](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc978014.aspx) means that the object is present in the directory, but not on that particular domain controller. This can happen for instance with partitioned directories or trusted/child domains.

You can use the `-Domain` and `-Server` parameters for connecting to a specific domain and/or server. Default is to connect to the PDC emulator of the domain of the current user.

Comment: I tried with adding `-Domain` and `-server` parameters with the values, it resulted with another exception saying `Set-GPRegistryValue : Value does not fall within the expected range.`

Comment: @BasavarajuBK Your registry value is a DWORD, so change `-Value "1"` to `-Value 1`.

Comment: Apology I missed out in editing that in the question. Actually The value is without double quotes. So its like this.
`Set-GPRegistryValue -Name "User Profiles" -Domain "mydomain" -server "myserver.com" -key "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\System" -ValueName "DisableForceUnload" -Value 1 -type DWord`
Still it throws the same exception.

Comment: Post a new question with the exact command and error message.